# MAUI ContentView doesn't bind the properties

Tags: maui

I like to create a custom component with MAUI. For this reason, I create a `ContentView` and I added some `BindableProperty` like this one:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty UserAnswerProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(UserAnswer), typeof(string), 
        typeof(DictionaryHeader));

public string UserAnswer
{
    get => GetValue(UserAnswerProperty) as string;
    set => SetValue(UserAnswerProperty, value);
}
```

Now, I added the XAML to display an `Edit` and I want to bind the `BindableProperty` *UserAnswer* to this component. So, I wrote this XAML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:bh="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse.Behaviors"
             xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse"
             x:Class="LanguageInUse.Components.WordCheck"
             x:Name="wc">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="editAnswer" Text="{Binding UserAnswer}">
        <Button x:Name="buttonConfirm" Text="Confirmed"
               Clicked="buttonConfirm_Clicked">
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

When I click the button and inspect the property *UserAnswer*, this is empty. So, the binding is not passing the value.

How can I do that? Do I have to create a *ViewModel* with an `ObservableObject`?

Comment: have you set the binding context?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that with the Binding, you are looking for data where the BindingContext is pointing to. Normally it is to your ViewModel. If you want to bind to the `ContentView` and its `BindableProperty` you reference them by the name of the xaml, in your case `wc`. There are other ways to do this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:bh="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse.Behaviors"
             xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse"
             x:Class="LanguageInUse.Components.WordCheck"
             x:Name="wc">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="editAnswer" Text="{Binding UserAnswer, Source={x:Reference wc}}">
        <Button x:Name="buttonConfirm" Text="Confirmed"
               Clicked="buttonConfirm_Clicked">
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `bindable properties` is to provide a property system that supports data binding, styles, templates, and values set through parent-child relationships. It is used to create properties for the elements. You can read the document about [Bindable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties).

If you want to use the `UserAnswerProperty` you created, you can create the entry like this:

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="editAnswer" UserAnswer = "text">
        <Button x:Name="buttonConfirm" Text="Confirmed"
               Clicked="buttonConfirm_Clicked">
 </VerticalStackLayout>
```

---

Besides, If you do not know how to bind the data to the text of the entry, you can create a viewmodel and realize the `UserAnswer` then bind the viewmodel to the Xaml

```
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       [ObservableProperty]
       string _userAnswer;
        public MyViewModel()
       {
           UserAnswer = "answer";
       }
      
    }
```

The code in the Mainpage code behind:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
```

The code in the Mainpage.xaml:

```
 <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="editAnswer" Text="{Binding UserAnswer}">
        <Button x:Name="buttonConfirm" Text="Confirmed"
               Clicked="buttonConfirm_Clicked">
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is quite straightforward. It is enough to add the `BindingContext` to the same page in a control like the `VerticalStackLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:bh="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse.Behaviors"
             xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse"
             x:Class="LanguageInUse.Components.WordCheck"
             x:Name="wc">

    <VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference wc}">
        <Entry x:Name="editAnswer" Text="{Binding UserAnswer}">
        <Button x:Name="buttonConfirm" Text="Confirmed"
               Clicked="buttonConfirm_Clicked">
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```